# Sum of two squares question

Tags: abstract-algebra, sum-of-squares-method

Which of the following statements is true for every value of $n$?

**A:** If $n$ is not a sum of two squares, then neither is 69$n$ 
**B:** If $n$ is a sum of two squares, then so is 34$n$
**C:** If $n$ is not a sum of two squares, then neither is 15$n$
**D:** If $n$ is a sum of two squares, then so is 14$n$

Comment: Have you ever heard of the [sum of two squares theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem)?  Can you make use of that here?

Comment: @JMoravitz Yeah, I understand where you're coming from but I'm still not sure as to how to tell which one is correct given any integer $n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [sum of two squares theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem) tells us that an integer $n$ is representable as the sum of squares of two integers if and only if the prime decomposition of $n$ contains no term $p^k$ where $p$ is a prime of the form $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ with $k$ an odd integer.

---

> A: if $n$ is not a sum of two squares, then neither is $69n$

False.  Consider $n=69$ in which case $n$ is not representable as the sum of two squares since it's prime decomposition is of the form $69=3\cdot 23$.  However, $69n=69^2=0^2+69^2$ is.

Note, it is possible however that $n$ and $69n$ are both not representable, for example when $n=7$

---

> B: if $n$ is a sum of two squares, then so is $34n$

True.  $n$ being a sum of two squares implies that there is no term $p^k$ where $p$ is of the form $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ with $k$ odd in $n$'s prime decomposition.  Multiplying $n$ by $34=2\cdot 17$ does not change this since neither $2$ nor $17$ are primes of the form $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$.  Thus, $34n$ is also representable as a sum of two squares.

Equivalently, $34 = 5^2+3^2$.  So, if $n=a^2+b^2$ you have $34n = (5^2+3^2)(a^2+b^2)=(5a+3b)^2+(5b-3a)^2$ by the [Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity)

---

> C: if $n$ is not a sum of two squares, then neither is $15n$

False.  The same counterexample as before works.  Let $n=15$.  Then $15n = 15^2+0^2$ is a sum of squares.

---

> D: if $n$ is the sum of two squares, then so is $14n$

False.  $n$ being the sum of two squares implies that in the prime decomposition of $n$ you have either $7$ not appearing at all or $7^k$ appears with $k$ even.  $14n$ will then have $7^{k+1}$ appearing with $k$ even and thus is not representable as the sum of two squares.

In fact, we can recognize that if $n$ is the sum of two squares, then $14n$ is *never* the sum of two squares.

Comment: Thank you! This makes much more sense to me now

Answer (score 0):

A is wrong: $69$ is not a sum of two squares but $69*69$ is.

B is true because $34= 25+9$.

C is wrong ( same as A)

D is wrong for the same reason as A.